# What's the `da` tool referenced all over the ex-models samples?

Tags: daml

I have been following the [daml documentation](https://docs.daml.com/) and managed to get the SDK 0.13.14 installed according to the documentation tutorials. However, when I check out the [ex-models](https://github.com/digital-asset/ex-models) samples they all refer to a `da` tool, for example:

```
da compile
```

or

```
da run damlc -- test daml/CrowdFunding.daml
```

but there isn't any `da` executable in the path only the `daml`.

**UPDATE** I get the following error using `daml build` on the `crowd-funding` sample:

```
skywalker@Zeus:~/code/ex-models/crowd-funding$ daml build
daml build: Not in project.
daml: An unknown error has occured
  context: Running build command.
  details: Received ExitFailure 1 when running
Raw command: /home/skywalker/.daml/sdk/0.13.14/damlc/damlc build --project-check
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`da` is a legacy tool that was only recently decommissioned. We have now updated the examples to use the new `daml` utility.

The new commands to use are:

- `daml build` to compile the project
- `daml test --color` to run all scenarios

I've now included makefiles in each project to run these conveniently.

Note that the error you're seeing with `daml build` comes from the fact that a project needs to be upgraded to work with the new tool. Previously, the `da` tool used `da.yaml` for the project configuration, the new `daml` tool uses `daml.yaml`.

You can use `daml init` to upgrade an old project to the new format (ie. converting `da.yaml` to the slightly different `daml.yaml`).

Comment: thanks! `da` doesn't work one to one with the commands of `daml`. See updated OP.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. We've now updated all the examples and I've edited my original answer to reflect that.